# I can not use PHP's strip_tags function with another function

Tags: php, string, strip-tags

I have a problem with PHP's `strip_tags` function. I have a list which includes a whitelist for html tags. That list is generated from a function like:

```
 setAllowedHtmlTags();
```

and output for this function is:

```
 "<a><table><br>"
```

I want to eliminate other html tags but this. Therefore I use strip_tags function as follows:

```
 echo strip_tags("sample text", setAllowedHtmlTags());
```

And here is my function:

```
function setAllowedHtmlTags()
{
    $db     = new PDO('mysql:host=' . host . ';dbname=' . DBNAME_SCHEMA, user, password);
    $sql    = "SELECT html_tag FROM allowed_html_tags_table";
    $query  = $db->query($sql);

    $tagList = "";

    if ($query->rowCount()){
        foreach($query as $row){
            $tagList .= $row['html_tag'];
        }
    }

    return htmlentities($tagList);
}
```

But it does not work. `strip_tags` function removes all html tags including mines in my whitelist. Can you please help me solve this issue?

Comment: Add the code of the `setAllowedHtmlTags` function

Comment: [Seems to work as expected](https://3v4l.org/RvojD)

Comment: Not real important but why would you use a function just to return `"<a><table><br>"`, why not setup a `const` or something.

Comment: Guess: `setAllowedHtmlTags` ***`echo`es*** the string, and doesn't ***`return`*** it…?

Comment: Because I get all the strings from database. And it returns exactly the string I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem, returning the value with html_entity_decode() function instead htmlentities() function worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Does your function `setAllowedHtmlTags()` really return what you told us?
Try a `var_dump(setAllowedHtmlTags());` to see what the function really returns.

Or maybe you wanted to call **g**etAllowedHtmlTags()?

Comment: Yes it returns exactly the string I expected.